# HTML/CSS: Dynamic Width of DIV containing UL/LI

Tags: html, css, dynamic, charts, width

I created a dynamic hierarchical Organizational Chart using the code at http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree. The width of the chart will vary depending on the number of positions.

The issue is if the width of the chart gets larger than the browser window, the org. chart gets messed up by staying the same size as the windows and scrambling the structure instead of extending the flow of the window with a scroll bar. (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euwx9qvq/)

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}


<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added a very large width to the DIV in the CSS to by pass it for now.

But the width is too large and the scrolling of white space can get too long.

What I'm trying to do is to get the DIV to be the right size dynamically without hard coding a width in the CSS and have the scroll bar scroll to the exact size and not more.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding this to the li of the tree

```
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
text-align: center;
```